# How to change students'grades using update statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change students'grade names from A, B, C... to (A) EXCELLENT, (B) VERY GOOD, (C) GOOD, ..., (F) FAIL
However, only (F) FAIL is being updated for all the students.

This is my table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hEob.png "primary_score"

This is what I have tried

```
UPDATE scores_primary SET grade= CASE student_id
      WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) > 70 THEN '(A) EXCELLENT' 
      WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) < 70 AND (ca1+ca2+exam) > 60 THEN '(B) VERY GOOD'
      WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) < 60 AND (ca1+ca2+exam) > 50 THEN '(C) GOOD' 
      WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) < 50 AND (ca1+ca2+exam) > 40 THEN '(D) PASS' 
      WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) < 40 AND (ca1+ca2+exam) > 30 THEN '(E) WEAK PASS' 
      ELSE '(F) FAIL' 
    END
```

Comment: Two issues: 
1) You need `CASE` to go along with the `WHEN` clauses.
2) You need to change `> 70` to `>= 70`, etc.

Comment: ... and you shouldn't have `student_id` in the `CASE` expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `student_id`, since we're simply updating every row. If you provide a value directly after `CASE`, that becomes the target of your `WHEN` statements. Since we're not comparing to `student_id`, in all cases it executes `ELSE '(F) FAIL'`. You can remove the excess checks, and use a simplified query that and covers all your cases:

```
UPDATE scores_primary
SET grade = (
    CASE
        WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) >= 70 THEN '(A) EXCELLENT' 
        WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) >= 60 THEN '(B) VERY GOOD'
        WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) >= 50 THEN '(C) GOOD' 
        WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) >= 40 THEN '(D) PASS' 
        WHEN (ca1+ca2+exam) >= 30 THEN '(E) WEAK PASS' 
        ELSE '(F) FAIL' 
    END
)
```

A few notes:

- The parenthesis in my solution are redundant here. I personally like to add them, because they clarify exactly what is being set.
- The excess checks (`AND (ca1+ca2+exam) < ...`) are completely redudant. If they were true, they're already being executed by the first check, so it's never evaluated.